# How do you scroll down in Gitbash?

Tags: ssh, terminal

Working on my SSH on gitbash. On the part where I type in vim ~/.ssh/config
It's completely blank so I enter the info below and want to save. How do I scroll down to --Insert-- to type in ":wq" to save it? I tried the tab button, pg dn, enter, arrow button.
Host *
AddKeysToAgent ...
IdentityFile ...
~
~
~
--Insert-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following command: <kbd>Esc</kbd> + `:wq`